# How to take multiple inputs from a user in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program where python will take multiple inputs until the user enters "END". Each input must be on a different line. I'm still new and learning python/programming in general so is there any way to do this? and how would I turn the inputs into a list?

What a demo might look like -

What are your hobbies?

painting

hiking

drawing

END

Answer (score 2):

You can read input with the `input()` function. You want to read till 'END' is entered by the user. So, read the input and check whether it is 'END'. If not `append` it to the list else exit the loop.

In codes you can do like this.

```
inputs = [] # list to  store the inputs

while True: # looping forever
    
    data = input('Enter the data : ') # read the data from user to variable data
    
    if data == 'END': # if END is read then exit the loop
        break
    
    else:
        inputs.append(data) # otherwise, append the input to the list
        
print(inputs) # display the list.
```

Hope this helps.!!